# Failure in pdf generation using flying saucer if input xhtml contains special characters

Tags: flying-saucer

I am using flying saucer to convert xhtml to pdf.
If the xhtml file contains special characters, pdf generation fails.
By special characters, I mean the characters which are outside of ASCII character set.
Written below is the sample xhtml (input.xhtml - ANSI encoded) which failed on pdf generation.
Following is the code which I used to convert xhtml to pdf.

```
    String inputFile = "samples/input.xhtml";
    String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
    String outputFile = "output.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
```

What should be done to ensure that pdf generation does not fails in any situation ?

Written below is another xhtml (input2.xhtml - UTF-8 encoded). It gets successfully converted to pdf.
But the generated pdf does not shows the special character Ɠ.
Why this character was not present in generated pdf ? What should be done to ensure these type of characters are present in pdf ?

Also the pdf generation failed when a NUL character (U+0000) was present in the input xhtml ? Is this because NUL is not permitted in xml.
If NUL is present in xhtml, can pdf still be generated using flying saucer ?

input.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My First Document</title>
    <style type="text/css"> b { color: green; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <b>Greetings Earthlings! ü </b>
        We've come for your Java.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

input2.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My First Document</title>
    <style type="text/css"> b { color: green; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <b>Greetings Earthlings! ü Ɠ </b>
        We've come for your Java.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of the question, the reason why the character `Ɠ` doesn't appear is because the default font has no representation for it.

If you want to print it, you have to embed a font which contain this character, for example Arial Unicode MS.

It can be done like this :

```
  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
  renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```